# Fields showing NO on Calculated Column

Tags: sharepoint, excel-formula, formula, sharepoint-online

Here is the formula I am using in calculated column, but it shows value no on column field:

```
=IF(ISERROR([Sep 22]/[Useful Life (in Years)]/12),"")
```

Comment: Please locate the Edit button right beneath the tags of your question and use that to open your post in the editor. Add there images of the data to which this formula pertains. This will help other volunteers who see your question for the first time to better understand your question and therefore be better able to help you.

Comment: I think you want `IFERROR` not `IF(ISERROR())` : `=IFERROR([Sep 22]/[Useful Life (in Years)]/12,"")`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax of `IF` function is like: `IF(<condition>, <true-value>, <false-value>)`. You are missing `<false-value>` in your formula.

Try using formula like below:

```
=IF(ISERROR(([Sep 22]/[Useful Life (in Years)])/12), "Error", "No Error")
```

**Documentation**: [Examples of common formulas in lists](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/examples-of-common-formulas-in-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3)